# Создание индикации загрузки данных при старте активити

Tags: android

Активити выводит большое количество информации из базы данных. Перед показом активити происходит задержка примерно в 20 секунд, что негативно влияет на пользователя. Если же поместить процесс загрузки в отдельный поток, то основной поток выводит пустую таблицу и ошибку об отсутствии данных. Как грамотно вставить ПрогрессБар, чтобы он отображался на экране до начала загрузки данных.

Comment: а что вы используете для того, чтобы получать данные в отдельном потоке? Корутины, RxJava, обычные Thread'ы ?

Comment: Отображайте данные только когда они готовы. До этого -- любую заглушку или ход загрузки.

Comment: Для создания потока использую Thread.